# Storing variable in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method `_get_token()` in my `Client` class that uses a GET request to get a new token. I then wanted to save the token and call on it for each GET request instead of having to keep calling the `_get_token()` method.

When my boss added the `if self._token is not None` part of the code it seemed to do this! But how?

```
class Client:

    def __init__(self):
        self._token = None

    def _get_token(self):
        if self._token is not None:
            return self._token

        response = requests.post("url", json="params", headers="headers")
        token = response.json()['token']
        self._token = token
        return token

    def get_json_response(self, endpoint, params):
        token = self._get_token()
        request_headers = self._get_default_headers(token)

        response = requests.post(url, json=params, headers=request_headers)
```

Comment: That code only doesn't save the token, for sure, there might be other code

Comment: None of the code shown here assigns to `self._token` any value other than `None`. Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "When my boss added the if self._token is not None part of the code it seemed to do this! But how??" Try to think logically about how the code is intended to work. What is the *purpose of* `self._token`? It should... save the token, as you describe, right? So. When you create an instance of the `Client`, is there a token to save yet? No, because you haven't retrieved it yet. So `self._token` is set to `None`, a special value to mean that we don't have the token yet. Now: try to talk through the logical steps that should happen in `_get_token`?

Comment: If we already have the token, should we `return self._token`? Why? If we *don't* already have it, should we `return self._token`? Why or why not? How do we get the token if we don't already have it? *How should we remember the token* when we get it?* Finally: compare all of that reasoning to what the code *actually does*. Where your boss added code, how does that relate to the intended logic? Is there any part of the intended logic that is still missing?

Comment: The code as shown is fetching the token every time, not caching it.  So it may *appear* to work but isn't saving any time.

Comment: I see that you titled the question, "Storing variable in `__init__`". Do you want to get the token when the `Client` object is created? Or do you want to wait until the first time it is needed? (**This** question is not rhetorical. We cannot decide for you what the design should be.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you for the explanations! As far as your question, I think I want to get the token when the Client is called

Comment: In that case, the code that gets the token should go into `__init__`, right? Since that is the code that runs when the Client is created?

Comment: @MarkTolonen - yes! How do I fix that so it 'saves' the token?

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually saving the token. Here is code that does this:

```
    def _get_token(self):
        if self._token is None:
            response = requests.post("url", json="params", headers="headers")
            self._token = response.json()['token']
        return self._token
```

You could further simplify the rest of the code by adding a `@property`:

```
    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._get_token()
```

Then the rest of the code can just write `self.token` and it will call `self._get_token()`, which uses the cached token.

Comment: Why not decorate the `_get_token()` directly? Also maybe better `if self._token is None: # make the request and bind to self._token` and then just a single return?

Comment: Good point. This will allow a simple migration from the code that uses `_get_token()` explicitly.

Comment: ahh good point about migration. but they will need to refactor the code at some point